# Why can't I compile my C code?

Tags: c, linker, include, include-path

I have these 3 files under **/Users/koraytugay**

```
checksum.h
enc.h
libsec.a
```

libsec.a is an archive file existing of checksum.o and enc.o

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ nm libsec.a

libsec.a(enc.o):
0000000000000090 s EH_frame0
0000000000000000 T _enc
00000000000000a8 S _enc.eh
                 U _strlen

libsec.a(checksum.o):
0000000000000078 s EH_frame0
0000000000000000 T _checkSumFor
0000000000000090 S _checkSumFor.eh
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay
```

This is how I try to compile my hello.c file:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:HelloWorld koraytugay$ gcc hello.c -L/Users/koraytugay -libsec -o koko.out
hello.c:4:10: fatal error: 'enc.h' file not found
#include <enc.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Btw, hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <enc.h>
#include <checksum.h>

// code here..
```

Comment: I _think_ it is because the compiler can't find the file named `enc.h`...

Comment: Err... not providing a valid path for enc.h?

Comment: Learn the difference between include <> and include "".  enc.h and checksum.h should be include "".

Comment: @cup I don't think the headers are in the same folder as `hello.c`.

Comment: @SeanBright Good thinking. Bravo.

Comment: Shouldn't it also be -lsec instead of -libsec?

Comment: @RandallCook Ah thanks... Yes.. Right. Can you provide this as answer so I can pick it?

Comment: @cup Yeah.. Not really..

Comment: This is for future: http://www.tugay.biz/2015/04/how-to-compile-and-link-c-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the lack of `-I.` switch to bring the current directory into the include path, the link specification should read `-lsec`, not `-libsec`. The linker takes the string after the `-l` switch, prepends `lib`, and looks for that. In other words, `-lfoo` implies that there should be a `libfoo.a` (static) or `libfoo.so` (shared) file on the link path (which itself is specified with the `-L` switch).

Answer (score 2):

You try to include `enc.h`, but it's not in your include path. You can add this to your gcc invocation to fix that:

```
-I/Users/koraytugay
```

Comment: @KorayTugay `-L` is for linking , `-I` is for including.

Comment: @KorayTugay `-L` only specifies the directories in which gcc should look for libraries (`.so` files). `-I` specifies directories in which gcc should look for header files.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks, I tried gcc hello.c -I/Users/koraytugay -L/Users/koraytugay -libsec -o koko.out
 but now I am getting: ld: library not found for -libsec I am sure libsec.a is there.

Comment: @KorayTugay did you try adding `-static`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am getting gcc -static hello.c -I/Users/koraytugay -L/Users/koraytugay -libsec -o koko.out
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: @KorayTugay `-libsec` or `-lsec`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to `#include` a file: with `"..."` and with `<...>`.

Essentially both are implementation-defined:

- `<...>` searches "a sequence of implementation-defined places", which is commonly referred as the include path.
- `"..."` searches "in an implementation-defined manner", which is usually the directory of the parent file. If the file isn't found, the `<...>` way (include path) is used instead.

The first way should be used for system headers as well as headers of libraries not directly included in the project, while the second way is to be preferred for headers belonging directly to the project.

Comment: `#include <...>` searches "a sequence of implementation-defined places" for the specified header. `#include "..."` searches for the named source file "in an implementation-defined manner"; if that fails, it then proceeds as for `#include <...>`. Generally you should use `"..."` for header files that are part of your project, `<...>` for system headers.